# Localizing nested Info.plist keys

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, internationalization, plist

I'm trying to localize a key in the InfoPlist.strings files which consists of a nested dictionary, like so:

```
baseKey = {
    secondDict = {
        "key" = "value";
    };
};
```

Is there any way I can access the inner key directly from the InfoPlist.strings file?

```
"baseKey.secondDict.key" = "newValue";
```

doesn't seem to work... Any ideas? I know I can replicate the dictionary structure in the strings file, but it contains some other information that I would prefer not to have in there.

Comment: That does not help, this is an InfoPlist.strings file, not Objective-C...

Comment: Also, what about localizing values inside arrays inside the plist?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it works like this:

Replace `"value"` with some localization identifier `newvalue_i18n_key`.

Then, in InfoPlist.strings for each language, do this:

`newvalue_i18n_key = "value";`

This is more similar to how NSLocalizedString works. To my reading, this is **not** what Apple says in [the official documentation regarding localizing plist files](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-102276), but it is what Apple does in [some sample code.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/ApplicationShortcuts/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016545-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569705/how-localise-the-key-uiapplicationshortcutitemtitle) comes up with the same answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can quickly access nested values this way, where "User" is the key to a NSDictionary and "Username" is a key to a NSString.

```
yourDict[@"User"][@"Username"]
```

Comment: This is true for accessing values from code. The question is asking about localizing values from the InfoPlist.strings file.