# How localise the key UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle

Tags: ios9, quickaction

How should I localise the key `UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle`?

I know how localisation works for keys like `NSLocationUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`: you put your localisation in the InfoPlist.strings file.

However, those are unique keys at the route of the document.

In this case, I'll have one `UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle` for each quick action, nested inside a dictionary and and array.

How can I localise these nested values?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Despite UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle not being 'unique' because there are multiple arrays, you can specify the value of that key to link up to the key in InfoPlist.strings.

### In Info.plist,

"UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle" : "shortcutTitle1"

### In InfoPlist.strings,

shortcutTitle1 = "localised string value goes here for the first shortcut title in the info plist array"

## Taken from Apple's sample application example.